# Adding C++ code in C program - expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘this’

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I am building a C program with no problem on CentOS using provided Makefiles in its distro package. However I need to modify source files and I need to use iqxmlrpc and boost libraries for that purpose. I have changed Makefiles respectively but when I want to build the package I get following error:

> ../src/libiqxmlrpc/libiqxmlrpc/except.h:9:21: error: stdexcept: No such file or directory
>   ../src/libiqxmlrpc/libiqxmlrpc/except.h:10:18: error: string: No such file or directory
>   In file included from ../src/libiqxmlrpc/libiqxmlrpc/libiqxmlrpc.h:17,
>                    from redir.c:2617:
>   ../src/libiqxmlrpc/libiqxmlrpc/except.h:14: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'iqxmlrpc'
>   
>   ... followed by many other errors ...

I believe above error is because iqxmlpc is written in c++ and gcc is treating it as C so I tried followings:
1) Use g++
2) Use gcc -x c++

Doing above, error changes to a lot of following in many header files:

> error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘this’

All the lines that compiler is complaining somehow have this or delete keywords as parameter. See below:

> int net_route(struct in_addr *dst, int delete);
>   or
>   extern int gad_new(struct gad_t **this)

Do you have any idea how can I fix this? Frankly, I have no idea what using 'this' or 'delete' mean as parameters. Are these only parameter names that gcc ignores the rule that we can not use keywords?

------------------------------
BTW, original programmer have used nested functions all across his code which were compiled fine using gcc. when I switch to g++, compiler complains about function-definition not being allowed in another function. Is there any way I can tell g++ to ignore this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those weren't keywords in C, they are in C++.

You will have to rename those parameters before the code will compile in C++.

You may run into other porting issues related to C++'s stricter type checking before you are done.

Another option is to keep the C and C++ code in separate files, and use `extern "C"` in the C++ code for every function call that must cross the boundary.  Since your C code extensively uses nested functions and other features not permitted in C++, this is probably your quickest approach.

Comment: extern "C" saved my life and I didn't have to rename all occurrences of this and delete, etc. keywords. Thanks for the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

`this` and `delete` are reserved keywords in C++ (*not in C though*) . You cannot use these as variable names when compiling with `g++`.

Its better to use different variable names in parameters and then compile with `g++`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right. However I could workaround the issue more quickly using extern "C" rather than renaming all the problematic variables.